# Lift is for car so what is for bike?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, etymology

The word lift generally means for car. Then what is for bike?

Eg: Can I get a lift?

Meaning, can I ride in your car?

Similarly, I want to know how can we say for "Can I get a lift with you on your bike?" or simply asking a lift on bike?

Comment: I would just say "a lift".

Comment: However you phrase it, I think my reply would be "You won't fit in the pannier."

Answer (score 1):

> Can I get a ride?

Derived from *riding a bike*. Although it can be confused with getting a ride in a car, which is often said instead of *lift*.

Comment: I think there is a UK/US difference in this: in the UK, it is not common to offer or ask for "a ride" in a car, and if I heard it I would think they were talking about going out for a drive for pleasure, rather than just to get somewhere. I believe it is much more common (almost to the exclusion of "a lift") in the US.

Comment: Interesting, I almost exclusively hear "a ride" in Canada.

Comment: In the US movie `The Grapes of Wrath`, he asks `How about a lift` for a truck. Seems `lift` was used in the US long time ago.